# VBA EXCEL : Find a text on range and copy cell that contains the vlue and paste on next sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I would like to ask how will i find a text in excel vba in main sheet column B and copy the cell that contains the text and paste it to thwe other sheet.

So far ive try to record a macro which will do the trick but i'm unable to fix the code . Can someone help me..Thankds
[i would like to search spouse soi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fAWa.png)

[image]

**Code for copy/paste**

```
Range("B:B").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="SPO SOI:", After:=ActiveCell, LookinIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Cells.Find(What:="SPO SOI:", After:=ActiveCell, LookinIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Deactivate
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets("STATUS").Select
    Range("P" & Lastrow).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: Why are you not simply using something like INDEX and MATCH or VLOOKUP or any other LOOKUP function? In other words, why do you need VBA at all for this?

Comment: What part of your code isn't working?  (Just the `Cut` instead of `Copy`?)  (P.S.  If you copy the code into your question, instead of just a picture of it, we could try it in our copies of Excel and see whether there is anything weird going on.)